# Named query to work out average

Tags: jpa, jpql

im looking for a bit help on this as im a little confused

i have created an entity which stores marks for a user

basically i want to create a named query to use, and one that automatically works out the average, only issue is i only want a selected columns to be averaged

currently the table is :

```
@Entity(name = "MARKING")
public class Marking implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Person marker;

    @ManyToOne
    private Project project;


    private String markingCompleted, markSectionOne, markSectionTwo, markSectionThree, markSectionFour,
            markSectionFive, markSectionSix, markSectionSeven, markSectionEight,
            markSectionNine, markSectionTen, markSectionEleven, markSectionTwelve, markSectionThirteen, markAdjust, overalMark, thirdMarker, plagorism;
```

What i am asking, is how should i structure the query that would only work out the average for markingSectionOne - Thirteen

Thanks guys

EDIT

I have added this into my Facade, but it does not seem right is it ?

```
public TypedQuery<Double> markingAvg(Project id) {
    System.out.println("id = " + id);
    TypedQuery<Double> query = em.createQuery("select ((m.markSectionOne + m.markSectionTwo + m.markSectionThree + "
            + "m.markSectionFour + m.markSectionFive + m.markSectionSix + m.markSectionSeven +"
            + "m.markSectionEight + m.markSectionNine + m.markSectionTen + m.markSectionEleven +"
            + "m.markSectionTwelve + m.markSectionThirteen) / 13.0) from Marking m where m.project = :id", Double.class);
    query.setParameter("id", id);
    double avg = query.getSingleResult();
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First approach is to calculate average at database side and then retrieve result:

```
TypedQuery<Double> query = em.createQuery("select ((m.markSectionOne + ... + m.markSectionThirteen) / 13.0) from Marking m where m.id = :id", Double.class);
query.setParameter....
double avg = query.getSingleResult();
```

Other way is to Select your entity and then calculate average in java:

```
TypedQuery<Marking> query = em.createQuery("select m from Marking m where m.id = :id", Marking.class);
query.setParameter....
Marking m = query.getSingleResult();
int sum = m.getMarkSectionOne() + ... + m.getMarkSectionThirteen();
double avg = sum / 13.0;
```

Comment: Could you check the edit i made to my question is that right ?

Comment: It looks like you want to `GROUP BY` project.